# Data structure for storing some training models (keras in R for regressin problem)

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am using keras in R to train a model for a regression problem (NN).

I trained the model with different variables, How can I store these different models? which data structure should I use?

I used "keras_model_sequential" to train these models.

the class of these models is:

```
[1] "keras.engine.sequential.Sequential"
[2] "keras.engine.training.Model"
[3] "keras.engine.network.Network"
[4] "keras.engine.base_layer.Layer"
[5] "tensorflow.python.module.module.Module"
[6] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.tracking.AutoTrackable"
[7] "tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base.Trackable"
[8] "python.builtin.object"
```

Comment: As Keras is built on tensorflow, take a look at:
https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_save_and_restore/ specficially the save_model_tf function.

Comment: Yes, `save_model_tf()` is the recommended way.